# How to store customer sales coming through a referrer site?

Tags: php, opencart

This is the url that has referrer sent through the URL.

```
http://www.myshop.com/index.php?referrer=xyz
```

I'd like to know how to store customer sales that took place on that very visit. I am thinking of using cookies to do this. Any better options?

Comment: Cookies are okay. Also you may need some fraud control based on IP, User-Agent etc.

Comment: @enenen Do you think making the cookies expire at the end of the session (ie when the user closes the browser) is accurate enough to store customer sales that took place on that very visit? The cookie value will get eventually stored in the database for record.

Comment: In our website cookie expiration could be changed. By default it's 30 days. We have an option to stop repeat sales, also. We track click  and visitors also, but it's possible to stop repeat sales without them. Just generate some hash (in the cookie) and `on duplicate` you will not track the sale. Not tested, just ideas...

Comment: @enenen Thanks for the suggestions. Also how would you suggest fraud control based on IP and User-Agent? Is it more like PHP-based solution or client-script?

Comment: Oh, it should be server-side. Simply we have tables for clicks, for visitors etc. Then when a sale comes we are checking for some dependencies with the other tables. It would be too long to write here. :)

Answer (score 1):

No need to code anything. Hope you are using the new version of Opencart. It has the in-built affiliate system. So you can create an Affiliate (dummy) and share the URL for refer. So Opencart handles everything. You can check the sales and other stuff under reports -> affiliate -> commission.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_GET['referrer']` to capture the referrers code or name.
Store it in a variable and save it to a database to keep a record of who has been referred to your site.